# js move object with arrow keys (only once)

Tags: javascript

Hi I've taken the code (to move objects with arrow keys) from some internet template. Since then, I've limited the area that the object can be moving around but I still have a problem that when I press an arrow key the object moves more than necessary, I just want to move it 20px in the appropriate direction, regardless how long the key is pressed.

Here are the functions:

```
var GameInput = (function() {

var pressedKeys = {};

function setKey(event, status) {
  var code = event.keyCode;
  var key;

  switch(code) {
    case 32:
      key = 'SPACE'; break;
    case 37:
      key = 'LEFT'; break;
    case 38:
      key = 'UP'; break;
    case 39:
      key = 'RIGHT'; break;
    case 40:
      key = 'DOWN'; break;
    default:
      // Convert ASCII codes to letters
      key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
  }

  pressedKeys[key] = status;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  setKey(e, true);
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  setKey(e, false);
});



function isDown(key) {
  return pressedKeys[key];
}

return {
  isDown: isDown
};
```

})();

And the function calling it:

```
function update() {


    if(GameInput.isDown('DOWN')) {
        if(player.y < canvas.height - player.sizeY) {
            player.y += 20;
        }
    }

    if(GameInput.isDown('UP')) {
        if(player.y > 0) {
            player.y -= 20;
        }
    }

    if(GameInput.isDown('LEFT')) {
        if(player.x > 0) {
            player.x -= 20;
        }
    }

    if(GameInput.isDown('RIGHT')) {
        // Don't go out of canvas
        if(player.x < canvas.width - player.sizeX) {
            player.x += 20;
        }
    }

    // You can pass any letter to `isDown`, in addition to DOWN,
    // UP, LEFT, RIGHT, and SPACE:
    // if(GameInput.isDown('a')) { ... }
}
```

I understand why it does what it does but I have not been able to modify it to only move 20px regardless how much time a key is pressed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `keyup` event to allow the operation to repeat only when a new key is pressed. Something like:

```
var allowRepeat = true;
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (allowRepeat) {
    setKey(e, true);
  }
  allowRepeat = false;
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  allowRepeat = true;
  setKey(e, false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not seem to have changed anything. I tried to put in in jsfiddle but it does not work. Here's the whole js file http://pastebin.com/utZeM3iJ Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think your logic is a little reverted, what you want is to disallow update 'before key up is fired', from your code, as long as the keyUp event is not fired, `isDown('XXX')` is still true..

So this is what you need: (you should do some refactoring, but this should work)

```
var GameInput = (function() {
    ....

    var _allowUpdate = {};

    function setKey(event, status) {
        var code = event.keyCode;
        var key;

        switch(code) {
            case 32:
                key = 'SPACE'; break;
            case 37:
                key = 'LEFT'; break;
            case 38:
                key = 'UP'; break;
            case 39:
                key = 'RIGHT'; break;
            case 40:
                key = 'DOWN'; break;
            default:
                // Convert ASCII codes to letters
                key = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
        }
        // This checks whether it's the first time the key being pressed.
        allowUpdate[key] = !pressedKeys[key] && status;
        pressedKeys[key] = status;

    }

    function allowUpdate(key) {
        _allowUpdate[key] ;
    }

    return {
        allowUpdate: allowUpdate
    };
}

function update() {

    if(GameInput.allowUpdate('DOWN')) {
        if(player.y < canvas.height - player.sizeY) {
            player.y += 20;
        }
    }
    .....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Not sure if I misunderstood something but now I cannot move down at all. Here's full code: http://pastebin.com/QQq5UYM0 Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the answer a bit, I didn't read through your whole example, I believe it can be refactor to be more intuitive, but maybe you can try whether this updated solution works?

Comment: Thank you. It returns: Uncaught TypeError: GameInput.allowUpdate is not a function

Comment: Maybe my function name allowUpdate collide with the variable name? Can u try changing the function name to say, allowMove?

Comment: updated the answer again, please try, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the approach completely: http://pastebin.com/TtruZd76 - I do things on keyUp.